# How to catch empty input value within MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I need to find multiple IDs within a table, but in some cases the search ID is missing. There is no way around this and I can not put this into programming application logic as it is a grafana dashboard filter. In case no filter it will provide no value at all for the variable.

Minimal example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
where
    -- try to catch empty value
    case
        when "$filter_ids" then

        id in ($filer_ids) 
        -- id in ('1','2')
        -- find_in_set(id, 1,2)
    end
    AND other_id = 4

-- Possible values for $filter_ids:
-- ''
-- '1'
-- '1','18'

-- Alternativ cases, also possible:
--    empty for no value
-- 1
-- 1,18
```

I tried both, find_in_set and IN. But both result in an MySQL error in case there is no value (no filter set).

How could I catch this in MySQL?

Comment: What should the output be when the filter is empty?

Comment: the filter will be ignored, so show all results if there is no additional criteria. In reality there are many AND other_id = 3 ... which will filter the results furter.

Comment: Where the `$filter_ids` have quoted values, is it the numeric value that should be matched to, or the textual value? (i.e. is `'1','18'` actually `1` and `18` or `'1'` and `'18'`?

Comment: both cases seem to work if present. The data field in MySQL is integer. Within grafana there is the option to output either quoted or non quoted ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty string to IN or FIND_IN_SET, if you have no ids. that would nozt produce an error

> ```
> CREATE tABLE TEST(id int)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id in ("") OR FIND_IN_SET(id,'')
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf6791ae633be3e12a1fa468980fd3fe)*